# rstrip, split and sort a list from input text file

Tags: python-2.7

I am new with python. I am trying to rstrip space, split and append the list into words and than sort by alphabetical order. I don’t what I am doing wrong.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list(fh)
for line in lst:
   line = line.rstrip()
   y = line.split()
   i = lst.append()


k = y.sort()
print y
```

Comment: Hi @Keiriso, have you tried using `lst = open(fname).readlines()`. You are opening the file, but not reading anything from it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. the list (lst) needs to be appended with the text file (line) in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to fix my code and the expected result output.
This is what I was hoping to code:

```py
name = input('Enter file: ')
handle = open(name, 'r')
wordlist = list()
for line in handle:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word in wordlist: continue
        wordlist.append(word)

wordlist.sort()
print(wordlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2.7, I believe you need to use `raw_input()` in Python 3.X is correct to use `input()`. Also, you are not using correctly `append()`, Append is a method used for lists.

```py
fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ") # Stores the filename given by the user input
fh = open(fname,"r") # Here we are adding  'r' as the file is opened as read mode
lines = fh.readlines() # This will create a list of the lines from the file

# Sort the lines alphabetically
lines.sort()

# Rstrip each line of the lines liss
y = [l.rstrip() for l in lines]

# Print out the result
print y
```

Comment: Thanks Enrique for your suggestion. I need to be able to use the for loop to append the lst, rstrip the spaces,split the text into words and sort them alphabetical order.